# Check whether any of multiple values exists in an array

Tags: javascript, html

**(This question has been changed a bit since some of the answers were posted. That is why they might seem a bit off-topic and/or out of context)**

Hello! So basically, I have this string that is entered by a user (a caption for an image, for example), and an array of links/words that I want to "block" the user from entering. (This would be to prevent from swearing, advertising etc.)

So I need some code that checks whether a certain value exists in an array.

This is my array:

```
var blockedUrls = ["https://google.com", "https://facebook.com"]
```

and this is the values I want to check

```
var userInput = "Hello! Check out my cool facebook profile at https://facebook.com";
```

(This would normally be set to a value fetched from an input of some sort, the static text is just to simplify)

So this is what I have tried:

```
let values = userInput.split(" ");
values.forEach((i, value) => {
    // inArray is a made-up-function in order to better explain my intention
    // The function I need here is a function that can check whether the value of the "value" variable exists in the "blockedUrls" array.
    if(value.inArray(blockedUrls)) {
        return alert(`You can't say that word! [${value}]`);
    }
});
```

So a summary: How do I check if any of multiple values exists in an array?

Comment: Suggestion : It would be good if you tag your question with right flags which is this case are **html** and **javascript**. So that you can get answer faster from the right community.

Comment: At first glance, I've noticed that you misspelled length twice. 
This may not fix your problem.

Comment: Having a list of unallowed links is a form of validation. This is typically done server-side to ensure security, as there is no way to side-step server validation, but plenty of ways to side-step client validation.

Comment: Also at first glance: `unAllowedLinks[0, 1, ]` is an error

Comment: There's a typo in `isEmpty` : you put `lenght` instead of `length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to change the number of values in `unAllowedLinks` you’d be better off using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like so:

```
function updateImage() {
    if (unAllowedLinks.indexOf(document.getElementById('myFile').value) > -1) {
        alert("This link is reserved");
    } else {
        // Use the value
    }
};
```

Comment: Whoops, looks like you beat me to the punch. By 11 seconds lol.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if a value is in an array by using `indexOf`

```
var value = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
if (unAllowedLinks.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    // value is in array
}
```

`-1` is returned when the value is not found in the array, else it returns the index of the value.

Comment: And if you're using a recent browser, [Array has an `includes` function that returns a Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: Yup depending on your need though no IE11 or down. So for some slow moving businesses that's a no go. But great to include. Thanks!